# OpenCV VideoCapture removes alpha channel from video

Tags: java, opencv, video-capture, rgba

I have video with alpha channel and I am trying to place it over another video as follows:

```
public static void overlayImage(Mat background, Mat foreground, Mat output, Point location) {
        background.copyTo(output);

        for (int y = (int) Math.max(location.y, 0); y < background.rows(); ++y) {

            int fY = (int) (y - location.y);

            if (fY >= foreground.rows()) {
                break;
            }

            for (int x = (int) Math.max(location.x, 0); x < background.cols(); ++x) {
                int fX = (int) (x - location.x);
                if (fX >= foreground.cols()) {
                    break;
                }

                double opacity;
                double[] finalPixelValue = new double[4];

                opacity = foreground.get(fY, fX)[3];

                finalPixelValue[0] = background.get(y, x)[0];
                finalPixelValue[1] = background.get(y, x)[1];
                finalPixelValue[2] = background.get(y, x)[2];
                finalPixelValue[3] = background.get(y, x)[3];

                for (int c = 0; c < output.channels(); ++c) {
                    if (opacity > 0) {
                        double foregroundPx = foreground.get(fY, fX)[c];
                        double backgroundPx = background.get(y, x)[c];

                        float fOpacity = (float) (opacity / 255);
                        finalPixelValue[c] = ((backgroundPx * (1.0 - fOpacity)) + (foregroundPx * fOpacity));
                        if (c == 3) {
                            finalPixelValue[c] = foreground.get(fY, fX)[3];
                        }
                    }
                }
                output.put(y, x, finalPixelValue);
            }
        }
  }
```

When I run this function I get Nullpointer exception since apparently foreground Mat which is taken from VideoCapture like this:

```
capture.grab() && capture.retrieve(foregroundMat, -1);
```

retrieves only rgb image and removes alpha channel. 
The video file originally is perfectly fine, and it retrieved mat should be in rgba format but it is not. What might be a reason to this issue?

Comment: Which file format are you using to preserve the alpha channel in videos? `webm` video format ?

Comment: Hello, I use `webm` and `mov` formats

Comment: can you share the code where you have initialized `capture` object?

Comment: @ZdaR here is the code snippet 
        `this.trainerCapture = new VideoCapture(videoFile);`

Comment: Can you share the input video file ?

Comment: Unfortunately no since it is private data, but I checked this video and it has alpha channels so video is not the issue.

Comment: I completely agree with your view point, but I am not sure about the codecs, etc. in your video file. It would be helpful if you either upload a small segment from your private video files or look up for an open source video file which can reproduce the same issue ?

Comment: As you suggested I tried different video file, you can find it [here](https://www.videvo.net/video/camcorder-overlay-with-alpha-/162/) but again I am getting an error: `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3`  in this line `opacity = foreground.get(fY, fX)[3];` It happens to any other video, that is why I assume that VideoCapture opens the video and grabs frame incorrectly.

Comment: That was helpful, I will get back to you soon as to why the frames are still in RGB format, till then you can attach this video along with your question, so that other people may also contribuute

Comment: Video is in webm format and VP8 codecs are used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, OpenCV does not supports fetching video frames with Alpha channel. This is evident from this [code snippet](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp#L1101). The authors have conveniently assumed that a video file would always have RGB frames.

A quick hack could be replacing `AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24` with `AV_PIX_FMT_BGRA` at the relevant places(2-3 instances) and re-building the library to get your code working. But this dirty hack would always generate RGBA frames for all video formats.

I am personally planning to create a [PR with this fix](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13394), but it may take some time.

Other possible solution would be to use some other third party library to fetch the frames of `.webm` or `.mov` format and then process it using OpenCV.

Comment: Have you already create pull request? It will be really usefull. May be you known another solution?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the PR link, But the maintainers said that the library already supports such behaviour. Please read the discussion in the thread and report if that doesn't satisfies your use case.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/13395) is the specific fix to this problem.