# How to make a video a circle using python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Hey guys so I'm working on this project where I need to transform a square video into a new video where all frames are circles and I'm kinda lost on how to do this in python. I searched online and say lots of answers but they were for single images and didn't work in my scenario so here I am asking for help in this matter.

**My current code (Its not much but could help :)):**

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(".\\VIDEO.mp4")
new_video = cv2.VideoWriter(".\\new_video.mp4", fourcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v"), fps=30, frameSize=(400, 400))

for x in tqdm(range(0, int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) - 1)):
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if ret:
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (400, 400))
        # ROUND FRAME CODE/FUNCTION CALL SHOULD GO HERE
        new_video.write(frame)

video.release()
new_video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Here is an example of an original frame:**

[image]

**So here is an example of how the frame should look like:**

[image: Round Frame Example]

Would this be something I could do with python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV VideoCapture removes alpha channel from video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53552698/opencv-videocapture-removes-alpha-channel-from-video) and [can videowriter preserve alpha?](https://answers.opencv.org/question/95065/can-videowriter-preserve-alpha/). Besides this, be aware that Not all decoders support an alpha channel (H.265/HEVC and VP9 appear to be able to do that). Moreover, the support of the alpha channel in video players is not always available.

Comment: That makes sense @JérômeRichard and probably why it didn't work with that piece of code, is there any other way I could do the rounding of the frame while working with videos?

Comment: They said FFMPEG supports that and there is a related Python module (ffmpeg-python). You could try it.